# Why does apscheduler not work in uwsgi mode?

Tags: flask, uwsgi, apscheduler

I have a flask application. This application mimics routing of vehicles in a city and when a vehicle reaches a designated point, I have to wait for 30-180 seconds before starting it again. I am trying to use apscheduler for this.

When the vehicle arrives I start an apscheduler job (with the 'date' trigger for X seconds). When the job fires, I do my processing.

This works well on my dev machine when I am running the flask app standalone. But when I try to run it on my production server (where the app is running in uwsgi mode) the job never fires. I have already set `--enable-threads=true` for the app, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

My relevant code is like this.

```
At my app initialization.  
   scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()   
   scheduler.start()
```

Whenever the trigger happens.

```
scheduler.add_job(func=myfunc, trigger='date', run_date=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=value)).
```

Anything I am missing in using apscheduler in uwsgi mode? Or any other options in flask to achieve what I want to?

Comment: A self contained example would shed light on your particular issue. Others with uwsgi have successfully used apscheduler, so that combination by itself is not the problem.

Comment: One thing I would check is the timezone mismatch, i.e. if you don't specify the run date in the past accidentally. Even though you specify run date using `datetime.datetime.now()` which returns current local datetime, and APScheduler also by default uses local timezone, uWSGI might cause some discrepancy.